# type " sudo chattr -i Cloud " to remove delete permission on folder "Cloud" error this "chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on Cloud"

Tags: permissions, permanent-delete

Opened terminal on partition where that folder exists and typed `sudo chattr -i Cloud` and I got an error saying
`chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on Cloud` cannot remove delete permissions on folder "cloud".

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: chattr only works on filesystems that support chattr.if you want to make a file undeletable remove the WRITE permissions: emptying a file is considered the same as deleting a file-name- from disk.